# unable to upload video in firebase

Tags: firebase, video, firebase-realtime-database, android-videoview

I am trying to upload video to Firebase But I am unable to do it. I can record video but, I am unable to upload it.
    The message popup " Nothing to Upload " I do not know what am I doing wrong.

```java
 public void upload(View view){
        if (videoUri!=null){
            UploadTask uploadTask=videoRef.putFile(videoUri);

            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    updateProgress(taskSnapshot);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing to upload ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Looking at the code, the only time that message would print is if the videoUri is null according to this statement `if (videoUri!=null)`. so...... that var is null before the code in the question exectutes, so you need to look elsewhere. Are you sure you want to name that var *videoUri* instead of *videoUrl*? (an 'L' instead of an 'I')?

Comment: @jay there is no issue with I and L.  just want to complete this task

Comment: I wasn't assuming there was, just mentioning it. The issue is the var is null so the code won't execute. You need to step through the code preceding this code and determine why that is.